# sound waves and atmospheric pressure

Tags: pressure

Is it possible to use sound waves (ultrasound/infrasound or whatever) in order to make some space have lower atmospheric pressure? Or maybe another way to achieve this? I was thinking that maybe sound waves (or other means) could create a temporary vacuum if applied appropriately in a space. Is this possible?

Comment: Hmmm I cannot help but think of resonators... I don't know what to answer yet, but meanwhile you could try googling them a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Waves will create spaces with very high and very low pressure, and leave spacs at the same pressure. You wouldn-t be able to cause a vacuum through sound. Its better explained in this video: (https://youtu.be/0K8zs-KSitc?t=58)

Plus it's really mesmerizing to watch...It's worth it :)